# Elevator Algorithm vs Shortest Seek-Time First (SSF) Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, comparison, seek

I'm trying to figure out some advantages that the elevator algorithm has over the shortest seek-time first (SSF) algorithm.

Wikipedia says: "However, the elevator algorithm is not always better than shortest seek first, which is slightly closer to optimal, but can result in high variance in response time and even in starvation when new requests continually get serviced prior to existing requests.

Anti-starvation techniques can be applied to the shortest seek time first algorithm to guarantee an optimum response time." [SOURCE] : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_algorithm

I'm not sure how to decipher this information. So my question is:

What are some advantages that the elevator algorithm has over the shortest seek-time first(SSF) algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

SSF might go back with the arm. The next seek time might be longer due to this. Also some data might stay in the buffer longer then expected:
Assume this:
Data comes into the buffer.
SSF for byte 1: 10
SSF for byte 2: 20

SSF writes byte 1.
New data arrived in the buffer:
SSF for byte to: 25 (changed due to the write of byte 1)
SSF for byte 3: 10

Byte 3 is written.

The elevator algoritm writes all data in one continues line, resulting in more direct clearing of the buffer and preventing some data staying in the buffer longer then anticipated. So it is just more predictable.

In real world:
Only important in high disk load situations.